# Передача text параметра через request

Tags: python, requests

я новичок в WEB Python. Я хотел бы знать, что я делаю неправильно. Суть моей программы заключается в следующем. Он заходит в аккаунт (т.е есть сеанс), затем в поле для текста вводит капчу, затем нажимает кнопку «Работа». Я написал этот код, но он не работает, он просто входит в мою учетную запись, скажите мне, что я делаю неправильно?

```
data = {'LOGIN_redirect': '1', 'login': login, 'pass': password, 'pliv': 15248, 'code': 'dukp54'}
r = s.post("https://www.heroeswm.ru/login.php", data=data, headers=HEADERS)
r.encoding = 'windows-1251'
e = requests.get('https://www.heroeswm.ru/object-info.php?id=304', data=data)
```

[image: поле для ввода]
[image: Сама кнопка]
[image: Form data]

Comment: Приведите всю необходимую информацию прямо в вопросе, а не по ссылкам.

Comment: Исправил, добавил изображения.